# Datetime substraction from DateTime value in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

How to subtract "year=117 month=1 day=28 hour=7 min=43 sec=10" from a `DateTime` in `c#`?

I have already tried like below

1. split the string using regex.
2. add each item with -ve sign to a current DateTime value.

But I think it's not an efficient way.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Just create another DateTime from the data you have and then subtract.

Comment: Btw.: Are you sure about `year=117`?

Comment: year, month, day, hour, min and sec are integers includes 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below Code as per you requirement to get desired Result. Replace your Date, Time, year values in "new System.DateTime(1996, 6, 3, 22, 15, 0);"

```
System.DateTime date1 = new System.DateTime(1996, 6, 3, 22, 15, 0);
System.DateTime date2 = new System.DateTime(1996, 12, 6, 13, 2, 0);
System.DateTime date3 = new System.DateTime(1996, 10, 12, 8, 42, 0);

// diff1 gets 185 days, 14 hours, and 47 minutes.
System.TimeSpan diff1 = date2.Subtract(date1);

// date4 gets 4/9/1996 5:55:00 PM.
System.DateTime date4 = date3.Subtract(diff1);

// diff2 gets 55 days 4 hours and 20 minutes.
System.TimeSpan diff2 = date2 - date3;

// date5 gets 4/9/1996 5:55:00 PM.
System.DateTime date5 = date1 - diff2;
```

Comment: It's not possible when  year = 0 or month =  0 or  day=0

Comment: There is no year 0 or month or day - what do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

you can try DateTime's subtraction.

for that first you have to make valid DateTime object from your information and then subtract that date from current date.

see below code,

```
int year = 117, month = 01, day = 28;
int hour = 07, minute = 43, second = 10;

DateTime timeToSubtract = 
   new DateTime(year > 0? year : 1, month > 0 ? month : 1, day > 0 ? day : 1, hour, minute, second);
DateTime subtractedDate =
   new DateTime((DateTime.Now - timeToSubtract).Ticks);
```

as you can see, we are creating a date time object with information we have (date and time which should be subtracted form current date time) by, `new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)` and then subtracting this from `DateTime.Now`, and then creating final date out of result of this subtraction.

here in last line we are creating a date (of past). this date is of specified time ago.

Comment: It's not possible when  year = 0 or month =  0 or  day=0

Comment: @SoorajPK updated answer. now year,month,day = 0 will mean, you don't want to subtract any day from current day.